# Adding an Option Page ACF data to Wordpress Shortcode in Functions.PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

My code:

```
    // Add Shortcode
function NavotFloatingDiv() {
    $nHeight = the_field('distance_from_top', 'options');
    $nPadding = the_field('div_padding', 'options');
    $nBackgroundColor = the_field('div_background_color', 'options');
    $nDisplay = the_field('div-display', 'options');
    $nDirection = the_field('left-right', 'options');
    $nLink = the_field('divlink', 'options');
    $nTarget = the_field('divlinktarget', 'options');
    $nLinkTitle = the_field('divlinktitle', 'options');
    $nContent = the_field('floating_div', 'options');
    return '<div id="Navot-Float" class="NavotFlaot" style="z-index: 99999999999; position: fixed; padding:' . $nPadding . 'px; background-color:'. $nBackgroundColor .' ; display: ' . $nDisplay . '; ' . $nDirection . ': 0px ;  top: '. $nHeightheight . '%;"><a href=". ' $nLink ' . " target=" ' . $nTarget .' " title=" '. $nLinkTitle .' "><div class="floater-navot-text"> ' . $nContent . '</div></a></div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'Floating DIV', 'NavotFloatingDiv' );
```

The information is stored, convinently with the Options page named Options. The goal is to create a mini-plugin for a floating DIV on the page in which the shortcode is placed. Dandy.

I can't quite find the problem right now, and I'd appreciate knowing what am I doing wrong in returning the HTML tags with the various retrieved variables.

Comment: Replace your `the_field` by `get_field`, 
because the first display, and the second returns

Comment: I'm afraid the website still crashes when I add this code to the functions.php ... Still thanks for the Explenation!

Comment: I think the first argument of `add_shortcode` should not contain special chars (like spaces)

Comment: And you have an error here : `<a href=". ' $nLink ' . "` (the dots are poorly positioned).

Comment: I've changed that, still no luck, but at least i'm cleaning it off. Thanks again!

Comment: I advise you to put the `WP_DEBUG` constant to `true` in `wp-config.php` file during your developement to see the php warnings and errors

Comment: Ok. I'll look it up!

Comment: Ok, the problem is definitely with the 'return' part.

Comment: Look at my answer, it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your corrected code :

```
add_shortcode('floating_div', 'NavotFloatingDiv');
function NavotFloatingDiv(){
    $nHeight          = get_field('distance_from_top', 'options');
    $nPadding         = get_field('div_padding', 'options');
    $nBackgroundColor = get_field('div_background_color', 'options');
    $nDisplay         = get_field('div-display', 'options');
    $nDirection       = get_field('left-right', 'options');
    $nLink            = get_field('divlink', 'options');
    $nTarget          = get_field('divlinktarget', 'options');
    $nLinkTitle       = get_field('divlinktitle', 'options');
    $nContent         = get_field('floating_div', 'options');
    return '<div id="Navot-Float" class="NavotFlaot" style="z-index: 99999999999; position: fixed; padding:'. $nPadding . 'px; background-color:'. $nBackgroundColor .' ; display: ' . $nDisplay . '; ' . $nDirection . ': 0px ;  top: '. $nHeightheight . '%;"><a href="'. $nLink .'" target=" ' . $nTarget .' " title=" '. $nLinkTitle .' "><div class="floater-navot-text"> ' . $nContent . '</div></a></div>';
}
```